# Где в ios 10 могут находиться файлы обновлений системы и прочий мусор?

Tags: ios, iphone

Имеется iphone 5s, в котором львиная доля места приходится на раздел "другое" (так называется раздел, если запустить программу itunes). Чтобы почистить место (это могут быть файлы обновлений, какие-то дампы и т.д.), сделал jailbreak, поставил файловый менеджер, показывающий всю корневую систему, и теперь пытаюсь найти, где же накопился весь этот мусор весом в 8,5 гб. В корне системы (это ios 10) вижу папки var, etc, usr, bin и т.д. Где могут находится обновления и т.д., то что я ищу, в какой папке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как узнать, сколько места занимает какая папка на диске?**

Найти в репозитории  какую-либо программу, отображающую статистику текущего использования разделов диска (желательно наглядно). Например, это может быть:

- [Disk Usage Analyzer (Baobab)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baobab) для Linux.
- [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) для Android.
- [Storage Space Plus](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/storage-space-plus/id1086277462) для iOS.